# Include index info in pdf man pages

Tags: pdf, man, conversion

I know that I can get to output manual page content with `man -Tpdf`. Many pdf readers can display and jump to specific points or sections in the document (i.e. by hitting tab from inside zathura). I want to know if there is a way to have man export index information along with pdf output, so I can browse pages more effectively that just using searching for section names?

Comment: I dont know of a pdf solution, but if you want to browse local man pages in your browser you might like the self-contained perl script [manServer](https://github.com/silviuvulcan/manServer) which parses man pages on demand and presents them in html, with clickable hyperlinks to other referenced man pages, and sometimes to internal links.  Once started you access it with your browser at url `http://localhost:8888` (port by default).